# Display C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct

When displaying the address of an individual member of a `struct/class`, the displayed address is the one of the whole structure.

Indeed,

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout<<&s<< " --- "<<&(s.x)<<std::endl;    
}
```

will print e.g. `0x7ffd4e882780 --- 0x7ffd4e882780`.

I found many posts that relate about manipulating individual members of a `struct` by using *recipes* such as

```
int S::*p = &S::x; 
S* ptr = &s;
ps->*ptr = 1000;
```

which may be related in some way to my question but I could not find one that explains why the individual address of `x` within the `struct` layout is the same (at least displayed) as the one of of the `struct`. I guess that I miss something obvious but do not find what. Would you have any idea ?